# TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `timestamps`?

Tags: mongoose, typeerror

At first, let me assure you I've searched everywhere I can about this error, but it seemed like nothing close to this sort exists. I used `timestamps: true,` in my mongoose scheme. And that should generate "created_at" and "updated_at" automatically in my schema. But this line throws this error: `TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: 'True' is not a valid type at path 'timestamps'.` Then I tried writing `timestamps: {Type:Date, required:true}`. In that case there is no runtime error, but when I post a request, it throws basically a validation error as timestamps is required but not provided in the body. And that obviously means the keyword `timestamps` is not working as it should be, cause it's supposed to be generated automatically.

**Trust me,** when I say that I tried to find the problem on my own as much as I can, because the thought of posting a new question here kinda gives me nightmare :3 love stack overflow though <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't pass it in the schema itself, pass `{timestamps: true}` as the options in constructor.

```js
const exampleSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For mongoose 5.x
timestamp is automatically created with the mongodb cluster you create.
Delete timstamps, and use 'date' if you really need timestamps
or you can use

```
$ npm install --save mongoose mongoose-timestamp
```

`const mongoose   = require('mongoose'), timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp')`

Comment: why install another dependency when timestamps are natively supported? Refer to the answer above